# Дублирование сообщений telegram bot. node-telegram-bot-api

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, telegram, node-telegram-bot-api

Не могу понять как решить проблему с дублированием сообщений. Может нужно ставить `bot.bot.removeListener('message', msg)` перед запуском /start, но это не привело меня к желаемому результату. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
class Move{
    public async start(bot: any){

        bot.onText(/\/start/, async (msg: any) => {
            bot.setMyCommands(commands)

            bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, ' Егор - ‍ разработчик ПО с большим стажем️! ‍♂️Егор - это талантливый специалист, который постоянно развивается в своей сфере и изучает новые технологии. Егор также ‍предан своему делу, что делает его ценным членом ‍команды и позволяет создавать высококачественные продукты. Егор - это профессионал, который стремится к совершенству и всегда готов помочь своим клиентам достичь их целей. ', startButton)

            bot.on('callback_query', (query: any) => {


                switch (query.data){
                    case "portfolio":
                        portfolioMove.getMove(bot, msg) 
                        break
                    case 'about': 
                        aboutMove.getMove(bot, msg);
                        break;
                    case "services":
                        servicesMove.getMove(bot, msg);
                        break
                    case "chat":
                        chatMove.getMove(bot, msg)
                        break
                }
            })
            
        })

    }
}

export default new Move;
```

Comment: js не знаю, но смею предположить, что дважды подписываетесь на событие callback_query, по этой логике, каждый такой клик будет увеличивать кол-во сообщений на 1 (опять же: только предположение)

Answer (score 0):

Я решил проблему вот таким способом, не знаю насколько он правильный, но теперь дублирования нет.

```
class Move{
    public async start(bot: any){

        const startMsg: any = await new Promise((res: any) => {
            for(let elem of [/\/start/, /\/restart/, /Вернуться к главному меню/]){
                bot.onText(elem, async (msg: any) => {
                    bot.setMyCommands(commands)
                    bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, ' Егор - ‍ разработчик ПО с большим стажем️! ‍♂️Егор - это талантливый специалист, который постоянно развивается в своей сфере и изучает новые технологии. Егор также ‍предан своему делу, что делает его ценным членом ‍команды и позволяет создавать высококачественные продукты. Егор - это профессионал, который стремится к совершенству и всегда готов помочь своим клиентам достичь их целей. ', startButton)
                    res(msg)
                })
            }
        })
         

        bot.on('callback_query', (query: any) => {

            switch (query.data){
                case "portfolio":
                    portfolioMove.getMove(bot, startMsg) 
                    break
                case 'about': 
                    aboutMove.getMove(bot, startMsg);
                    break;
                case "services":
                    servicesMove.getMove(bot, startMsg);
                    break
                case "chat":
                    chatMove.getMove(bot, startMsg)
                    break
            }
        })

    }
}

export default new Move;
```